# Does FHIR support self defined resource?

Tags: hl7-fhir

We have a need to display some extra content for diagnosticreport
checked the online document, seems we FHIR doesn't support self defined resource, right?

if can support, could somebody give me some reference?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See extensibility first - http://hl7.org/implement/standards/fhir/extensibility.html - you can add extra content, and it sounds like this is what you want.

There's no formal support for adding additional new types of resources - that's something that's planned but not done yet.

Answer (score 1):

There is an ability to use the Other resource for the purposes of defining custom resources - almost all of the elements are extensions and you use a code to identify what "kind" of resource it is.  Anyone can define a local code for a custom resource.